# Ubuntu Software Center for 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-center

I cannot find Ubuntu Software Center (USC) for 20.04 .  USC showed not only end user applications that were installed, but systems software applications, including kernels, that were installed, as well as the update history.  "Software" (gnome-software shown in `top` when the Software icon is activated) only shows user applications, not the kernel.  Has USC been discontinued?

I have looked at the various answers on Ask Ubuntu; in one such, it is claimed that `gnome-software` is the current equivalent of USC but unless there is a hidden configuration file for `gnome-software` to extend the actions and domains of `gnome-software` and instructions on how to configure it, it is not.

Comment: Start with `man gnome-software` Then `dpkg -S gnome-software` `dpkg  -L gnome-software;locate gnome-software` and read it.

Comment: *Has USC been discontinued?* Yes. https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/11/the-ubuntu-software-centre-is-being-replace-in-16-04-lts

Comment: There is no equivalent of USC, but if you want to view all installed packages, including kernels etc., then Synaptic Package Manager may be of use to you (you can install it via Ubuntu Software or GNOME Software). This tool is a little harder to use than USC, but it was there long before USC and shows the actual packages installed in the system. There's no update history however.

Comment: Why is USC not being re-instated?  This is a vital utility for any system, including a workstation, to understand system history.  Is there an extant USC equivalent for Ubuntu server, and if so, will to work with a workstation Ubuntu installation?

Comment: I already have ```Synaptic Package Manager``` (SPM) installed.  The only way I seem to be able to get a "record" of what is displayed is using a screenshot; there does not seem to be a text file output.   I shall be posting the output as a separate question about kernel versions and software update manager.  Although not a complete revision history, SPM seems barely adequate.  It does not seem to permit meaningful search filters with "wild-cards".